# How to force factory reset Samsung Galaxy S21 with low battery?

Tags: samsung, battery, factory-reset

My Samsung Galaxy S21 phone is damaged so the battery won't charge when the charger is plugged in. However, the charger still supplies power to the phone. It's been plugged in and sitting happily at 5% all day. I want to do a factory reset, but it says I need at least 10%. There is no possibility of that. I want to reset the phone before I get a new one from insurance and have to send in this one.

How can I force it to reset, or if not, still ensure I wipe all my PII before sending it to Samsung?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the state of your phone: Partially broken screen, working screen but can't boot into OS, or can boot into OS but battery level is stuck at 5%, i.e. when phone says it needs "10% for factory reset" from where is it saying that (hoping from within running OS but unclear).

Comment: Your phone comes with a 25W charger. If you are using that, here's a *wild guess that may not work* - try using an old 5A 2W charger or any lower rated charger

Comment: @MorrisonChang everything about the phone works fine other than it can't take a charge. Screen is fine, can boot into the OS, its just stuck at 5%. The Factory Reset option when you go to settings and search "Reset" is what is requiring 10%

Comment: @beeshyams its a usb-c charger so I don't know if they make low watt chargers for that? I tried plugging it into a usb 2 hub plugged into my power strip, no dice

Comment: Use a regular charger, USB chargers supply very low power comparatively, so slow charging in best of conditions //Even old 5V 2A or any other wall mounted charger you lay your hands on would give better results in usual condition //in damaged condition I can't say but worth trying

Comment: To add you get small hardware converters to type C that you plug into your old charger and other end USB C to your device

Answer (score 1):

I used a free 3rd party app ["Fast Factory Reset"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.dja.screenlock.activities&hl=en_US&gl=US) that warned about the battery but still let me do it. It worked fine.

I was not able to get my hands on a low watt charger to test. FWIW, I plugged my standard charger into a Kill A Watt and it registered 1/1.3 W. If I am able to get a low watt charger before I send it in to insurance, I'll update the answer.